# Lag length selection in levels-VAR before VECM: inclusion of exogenous variables

Tags: model-selection, vector-autoregression, lags, vector-error-correction-model

I am trying to estimate a VECM and I read in Asteriou´s book "Applied Econometrics" that

> "The most common procedure in choosing the optimal lag length is to
>   estímate a VAR model including all our variables in levels
>   (non-differenced data). This VAR model should be estimated for a large
>   number of lags, then reducing down by reestimating the model for one
>   lag less until we reach zero lags."

However, I will introduce a dummy variable in my model.

**Question:** should I include the dummy in this VAR or should I include the dummy only afterwards when I estimate the VECM?

Comment: What do you think about the answer?

Answer (score 1):

I would include the dummy variable(s) right away. For example, if the data generating process is well described by a VAR(1) and (strong) additive seasonality, then a sensible lag selection procedure will correctly suggest lag 1 if you include the seasonal dummies in the models among which you are choosing. However, if you do not include the dummies at the model selection stage, a VAR($p$) model could be suggested by the procedure instead, where $p$ could be equal to the seasonal period (e.g. 4 for quarterly data), as the (strong) additive seasonality will induce (high) autocorrelation at lag 4.